# Unable to patch logging.Logger.info called inside celery task

Tags: python, logging, mocking, celery, pytest

I want to test that a specific celery task call `logger.info` exactly once when the task is invoked with the `delay()` API.

And I want to do the test by patching `logger.info` .

I want to test as described here for the `Product.order` case https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/testing.html.

The setup is : python 2.7 on ubuntu 16.04 . celery 4.3.0 , pytest 4.0.0, mock 3.0.3.

I have the following file system structure:

```
poc/
   prj/
     -celery_app.py
     -tests.py
```

celery_app.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery import Celery

from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

app = Celery('celery_app')

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):

    logger.info('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

tests.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from mock import patch

from prj.celery_app import debug_task


@patch('logging.Logger.info')
def test_log_info_is_called_only_once_when_called_sync(log_info):
    debug_task()
    log_info.assert_called_once()


@patch('logging.Logger.info')
def test_log_info_is_called_only_once_when_called_async(log_info):
    debug_task.delay()
    log_info.assert_called_once()
```

I expect both tests to have success. 
Instead the first has success, while the second fails with `AssertionError: Expected 'info' to have been called once. Called 0 times.`

I expect that the evaluation of the expression `logger.info` inside `debug_task()` context evaluates to `<MagicMock name='info' id='someinteger'>` in both cases, instead it evaluates to `<bound method Logger.info of <logging.Logger object at 0x7f894eeb1690>>` in the second case, showing no patching.

I know that in the second case the celery worker executes the task inside a thread.

I ask for a way to patch the `logger.info` call when `debug_task.delay()` is executed.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: Patch it where you have used it: in `prj.celery_app`.

Comment: `@patch(prj.celery_app.logger.info)` gives the same results. Did you mean that? If no, please tell me. Thanks for your comment.